# Hide show text merging two functions

Tags: html, css, hide, show, fade

I am not comfortable with html programming. I have browsed a number of JQuery related forums and they offer very nice solutions, but I'd rather not starting using that library.
I use a function that works perfectly to display and hide a text with a fader. But the link remains visible.

[Here is a link to the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HR5tS/15/)

```
      <script>
function generateFader(elem) {
    var t = null, goal, current = 0, inProgress = 0;
    if (!elem || elem.nodeType !== 1) throw new TypeError('Expecting input of Element');
    function visible(e) {
        var s = window.getComputedStyle(e);
        return +!(s.display === 'none' || s.opacity === '0');
    }
    function fader(duration) {
        var step, aStep, fn, thisID = ++current, vis = visible(elem);
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        if (inProgress) goal = 1 - goal; // reverse direction if there is one running
        else goal = 1 - vis;             // else decide direction
        if (goal) {                      // make sure visibility settings correct if hidden
            if (!vis) elem.style.opacity = '0';
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
        step = goal - +window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;
        step = 20 * step / duration;     // calculate how much to change by every 20ms
        if (step >= 0) {                 // prevent rounding issues
            if (step < 0.0001) step = 0.0001;
        } else if (step > -0.0001) step = -0.0001;
        aStep = Math.abs(step);          // cache
        fn = function () {
            // console.log(step, goal, thisID, current); // debug here
            var o = +window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;
            if (thisID !== current) return;
            if (Math.abs(goal - o) < aStep) {            // finished
                elem.style.opacity = goal;
                if (!goal) elem.style.display = 'none';
                inProgress = 0;
                return;
            }
            elem.style.opacity = (o + step).toFixed(5);
            t = window.setTimeout(fn, 20);
        }
        inProgress = 1; // mark started
        fn();           // start
    }
    return fader;
}
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function () {



         var fader1 = generateFader(document.getElementById('showOrHideDiv1')); 

           document.getElementById('action1').addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
                fader1(1000);
            }
        );
         }
        );
</script>
```

Now I have found this function that allows to integrate the hidden / displayed text within a paragraph.

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

The CSS for the show and hid links of the 2nd function is:

```
     <style>   
       .more {
      display: none;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #36f;
      padding-left: 8px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
</style>
```

I am again terrible at coding. Does anyone know how to merge these two functions?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you're trying to do, or what in your jsfiddle isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: Well, I have a function that allows to do a "show more / show less" and another one that allows to create a fader, but with a link that doesn't disappear.They have been written by two different people. I'd like to have a "show more / show less" with a fader...

Comment: Still not 100% sure I understand your goal; is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/M87Nk/   (I didn't modify the js at all, just put the "show-hide" html inside one of the "fade" html blocks)

Comment: (Note that neither of the scripts you're cargo-culting here is particularly well-written; this could all be done far more easily with a CSS transition and some classname toggles. But I'm gathering that you're less in learning how to do this well than in just getting it done with...)

Comment: You're right. At least both functions are working now. I'd like to apply the show more/show less AND the fade to the same component, that is have one single function that would do both things.

Comment: I must also say that I would like the link to disappear, like in the show more / show less.